# Substantivierung reflexiver Verben

Tags: spelling, reflexive, nominalization

Wie werden reflexive Verben substantiviert?
Gibt es dazu feste Regeln?

Mit Bindestrich oder ohne:

> Sein Sichentwickeln oder Sein [S/s?]ich-Entwickeln?

Wird das Reflexivpronomen *sich* angepasst:

> Mein Michanziehen, dein Dichanziehen, sein / ihr Sichanziehen, unser Unsanziehen?

Funktioniert das auch mit dem Dativ:

> Mein Mirdiehaarefönen?

Oder mit Ergänzung:

> Er wusch sich ausgiebig – sein Sichausgiebigwaschen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§43 des [amtlichen Regelwerks](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) sagt:

> Man setzt Bindestriche in substantivisch gebrauchten Zusammensetzungen (Aneinanderreihungen), insbesondere bei substantivisch
> gebrauchten Infinitiven mit mehr als zwei Bestandteilen.
>
> [...]
>
> *das Auf-die-lange-Bank-Schieben, das An-den-Haaren-Herbeiziehen,
> das In-den-Tag-Hineinträumen, das Von-der-Hand-in-den-Mund-Leben*
>
> [...]
>
> E: Dies gilt nicht für übersichtliche Zusammensetzungen mit Infinitiv, zum
> Beispiel: *das Autofahren, das Ballspielen, beim Walzertanzen, das Inkrafttreten*

Zweiteilige Zusammensetzungen dürfen also zusammengeschrieben werden. Der Duden kennt ohne Bindestrich:

> Sichankleiden, Sichaufrichten, Sichausweinen, Sichorientieren, Sichvergewissern, Sichzurechtmachen

Man findet aber auch Beispiele, wo ein Bindestrich gesetzt wurde:

> **BRZ06/MAI.14590 Braunschweiger Zeitung, 27.05.2006**
> Kirche braucht Zeiten der Einkehr und des spirituellen Auftankens und Kraftschöpfens, ein Sich-Vergewissern über ihren Grund und ihr Ziel.
>
> **U11/NOV.01720 Süddeutsche Zeitung, 12.11.2011, S. 16; Wo bin ich?**
> Denn diese Geräte trennen zwei Tätigkeiten voneinander, die bislang in- und miteinander ausgeübt wurden: Das Gehen oder Fahren und das Sich-Orientieren.

Wie die Beispiele aus §43 zeigen, können diese Substantivierungen auch mehr als zwei Wörter umfassen. Dann müssen allerdings Bindestriche gesetzt werden:

> beim Sich-ausgiebig-Waschen

Aber schöner und kürzer wäre doch einfach:

> beim ausgiebigen Waschen

Die Frage, wie sich Possessivartikel und Pronomen zueinander verhalten, ist mangels Belegen nur theoretisch zu beantworten. Sie sollten in der Substantivierung im gleichen Verhältnis wie Subjekt und Pronomen im Satz stehen. Wenn das Verb nicht echt reflexiv ist, können verschiedene Personen auftreten:

> Daß **du** *mich* ständig kritisierst, nervt mich.
> **Dein** *Mich*-ständig-Kritisieren nervt mich.

Aber wieder: Warum nicht einfach –

> deine ständige Kritik (an mir), dein ständiges Kritisieren